# Select sum top 3 of last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have bellow snippet table.

[image: rating table]

Above the rating table i am saving the records of `vote` of `product_id` with `user_id` who have rated to that `product_id` with vote and `rating_date`.

Now here i have to fetch top 3 product_id who have max sum of vote in last 7 days (from current date).

Out put expected for max vote sum record of product_id :-

1) `product_id` 8965 have 403 max `vote` of sum of last 7 days

2) `product_id` 4024 have 36 max `vote` of sum of last 7 days

3) `product_id` 2015 have 5 max `vote` of sum of last 7 days

This is all the top 3 max sum of vote of last 7 days so i have fetch `produt_id` according to this output.

I have tried bellow snippet code but its wrong something.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(vote) AS 'meta_sum', product_id 
FROM rating 
where rating_date >= curdate() - INTERVAL '7' DAY
    AND rating_date < curdate() - INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY meta_sum DESC LIMIT 3") OR DIE(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $topexpert =$row["product_id"];
   $toprating =$row["meta_sum"];
  ?>
```

Comment: Define wrong, are you getting an error?

Comment: Your while loop is missing its closing `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace with these query

```
SELECT SUM(vote) AS 'meta_sum', product_id 
FROM rating 
where rating_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY meta_sum DESC LIMIT 3
```